# Make objects to move faster in lua issue

Tags: android, lua

I have created a game in lua. Everything seemed to work good in corona simulator. But when I installed the game on my device, he game begin to hang after 3-4 consecutive iterations. (Means when I clicked on 'replay' to play again, the game began to hang.
This is what I tried:

```
function animal()   
local animal=display.newImage("animal.png") 

    local z= math.random(1,1000)

      if z<=300
        then
        animal.x=330
          animal.y= centerY + 80

      elseif z<=650
           then
          animal.x= centerX + 60
          animal.y=centerY + 100

      else
          animal.x= 1180
          animal.y=centerY + 100
      end

        animal.trans=transition.to (animal, {time=1001, y=-150, alpha=1, onComplete = gameOver})
        animal: addEventListener ( "tap" , disapp )

function remove_listen_animal()
    Runtime: removeEventListener ( "tap" , disapp )
    return
end

function remove_animal()
    display.remove(animal)
end
end

local function disapp (event)                           
    local obj = event.target


    transition.cancel (event.target.trans)
    display.remove(obj)
    animal()


return
end

function gameOver()

    transition.cancel()
    remove_animal() --removes object from gameOver screen
    remove_listen_animal() --removes animal event listener
    scoreText.text=nil
    mainScreen() --This is the function invoked at very first when game is started. In order to restart the game,I re-invoked this function.

end
```

Now When I start the game,the first run goes perfect on device. But when game is over and I again tap the 'play' button to play, then game begins to hangs. 
Help me with this please?
Also, I want the speed of movement [as in transition.to()] of object to be fast. Can this be reason of game hanging after 2-3 iterations?

P.S I think the problem is in gameOver function. Is there any way by which all running operations get killed/ended when gameOver function is invoked? 
Because when I restart the game after closing it, again the first iteration runs fine, but later hangs again.

Help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [composer](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/) in your game? If not, composer will solve some problems about memory leaks when you used it right. Try this:

```
function remove_animal()
  display.remove(animal)
  animal = nil
end
```

And avoid making your functions visible in the global scope, always put local to it if that function is only needed in a certain scene.